# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working for iframe within the same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain-policy

I'm trying to access an iframe within a subdomain and get a cross domain error.


Here is the code of **example**.mydomain.com/iframe_test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://example2.mydomain.com/welcome.php" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#innerdiv',$('iframe').contents()).hide();
            },5000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code of **example2**.mydomain.com/welcome.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . "*");
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="innerdiv">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the line **$('#innerdiv',$('iframe').contents()).hide()** is executed, the following error occurs:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.mydomain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://example2.mydomain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I checked with Fiddler that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header was really returned in the response of welcome.php


Is it possible to access the contents of an iframe within a subdomain?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is used only for XHR.

What you need is called [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin).

You have to add `document.domain = 'example.com'` to your pages.

Comment: Where should we add that document.domain stuff? Can you elaborate a little more. Thank you.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati You need to add it to both of the pages into script tag. Basically the main page and the iframe page need to have `<script>document.domain = 'example.com'</script>` set

Comment: This doesn't work, I get: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': 'example.com' is not a suffix of ''.`

Comment: @MikeR what address of your document?

Comment: <script>document.domain = 'example.com'</script> where to paste is exactly.? I pasted it but didnt wrk properly.

Comment: Must use document.domain = 'localhost'; or your domain
You should open in web server, not a local file

Comment: This solution is deprecated

Comment: Note on deprecation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain

Answer (score -2):

I found this solution about "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in custom.unified.js with divi theme wordpress and i corrected by put this condition

```
        if (window.parent != window.top) {
    window.top && window.top.__Cypress__ ? r = window.parent === window.top ? window : window.parent : window.top && (r = window.top, window.top, window.self)
    }
```