# Sencha Touch Fileupload issue

Tags: php, extjs, file-upload, sencha-touch

I am using [File uploading component for Sencha Touch](https://github.com/kostysh/File-uploading-component-for-Sencha-Touch) to upload image in my sencha project.
Its working fine. But when i am trying to upload the image from another domain it gives

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "http://192.168.1.45". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.` 
error.

The issue is very clear, so i have tried by using `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` and also tried  `<script type="text/javascript">document.domain = '*';</script>`(Both together and also differently) but nothing happens. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362842/access-control-allow-origin-not-working-for-iframe-withing-the-same-domain)

Basically the php file which is responsible for image uploading is working properly for a result image is successfully uploaded but after that the json data is not returning in sencha, so that's causes the error.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Please help me to fix this.

Thank You...

Comment: Change `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to this `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] . "");`

Comment: tried but nothing happens. btw thnx for reply

Comment: i have found this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17639/iframe-protocols-domains-and-ports-must-match-error

Comment: Check this link as well http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

Another one: If you load up a file from your "local" filesystem, it is not where the PHP is running. PHP is in the server you got the JS from to your Browser ... So a Allow-Origin in the PHP File isn't useful. It would only be useful, if you would try to upload a file from the server to your client device the Browser is running on. Let me know what is your solution - I am snoopy ;)