# How to call javascript on svg embed into an Object tag without security error?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg

I generate Html/js/svg document to be used from a local computer.

When I try to execute my javascript I get this error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match
```

I found a stackoverflow answer about it: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362842/access-control-allow-origin-not-working-for-iframe-withing-the-same-domain)

I do not know what to put into document.domain as my html page is a local file.

the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/test.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id='test' data='test.svg' type='image/svg+xml'>
        Your browser doesn't support SVG
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

the javascript code is simple:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  const object        = document.getElementById('test');
  const svgdoc        = object.contentDocument;
 ...
}, false);
```

My script works fine with firefox 31.5.0 but not with google-chrome 41.0.

Thanks for your help