# iframe same origin policy issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am getting following error ,when trying to read iframe content whose src is other domain

```
SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://qa-xxx.abc.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://yyy.abc.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Now Suppose right now i am in https://qa-xxx.abc.com doamin and my iframe code is

```
<iframe src="https://yyy.abc.com" style="height: 100%; width: 105%;" id="id_description_iframe"></iframe>
```

while searching i found this solution [Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working for iframe withing the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362842/access-control-allow-origin-not-working-for-iframe-withing-the-same-domain)

So i did like that `document.domain = 'abc.com'`

Still same Issue,Any Solution will be Helpfull.

Comment: If you don't control code in iframe you can't do anything inside it. do you control both?

Comment: @charlietfl  i didnt get you,what do you mean by code control of iframe

Comment: Simple... is iframe on domain that you control and you are able to put code into that page?

Comment: yes i have access to https://qa-xxx.abc.com ,and i am only deploying my code there..

Comment: What exactly do you need to do between the 2? I have used document.domain in the past. But postMessage API is also useful api

Comment: if i am trying to read content of iframe its showing above error $("#id_description_iframe").contents().find("body").html()

Comment: did you put `document.domain` in both pages? ALso what exactly are you needing to do between the 2 windows?

Comment: basically you are saying in https://yyy.abc.com and https://qa-xxx.abc.com right?yes i put it

Comment: yes ... i have done that successfully in the past. Still haven't answered what exactly you need to be able to do. Glad to help but only if you answer questions

Comment: need to ask last thing in iframe src="yyy.abc.com/contact.html" do i need to add document.domain = 'abc.com' in contact.html also

Comment: depends on what you need to do with it

Comment: needs to read and change some content

Comment: well any page you load in iframe that you want to get inside...rules are the same. for minor issues though...using postMessage is safer

Answer (score 0):

You're violating Same Origin Policy. Add:
`document.domain = abc.com`
to both of the pages. Either directly in a script tag, or in a referenced js file.